# I am using dozer mapper. How i can set my default value to field if it is empty?

Tags: java, dozer

i need co convert a lot of string fields, and if field is empty, i want to set my own value. How can i do it? 
Write setters to all fields, i think it's not the best solution. Are there options in dozer mapper, for this operation?
Also i can write my own converter, but i want to know, is there any universal solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set [`map-null`](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/exclude.html) and [`map-empty-string`](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/exclude.html) to `false` to bypass the mapping of null or empty String values. For example:

```
<mapping map-null="false" map-empty-string="false">
  <class-a>org.dozer.vo.AnotherTestObject</class-a>
  <class-b>org.dozer.vo.AnotherTestObjectPrime</class-b>    
  <field>
    <a>field4</a>
    <b>to.one</b>
  </field>
</mapping>
```

However, if you want to set it to your own default value, then I think you will have to write a [Custom Converter](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/customconverter.html).